# Why 致 in "一致" (unanimous)?

Tags: meaning

一 makes sense to me, because it means "one".  Collins Dictionary defines '一致' as 'unanimous', which itself originates ["from Latin *unanimus* "of one mind, in union," from Latin  *unus* "one" (from PIE root [*oi-no-](https://www.etymonline.com/word/*oi-no-?ref=etymonline_crossreference) "one, unique") + *animus* "mind, spirit" (see [animus](https://www.etymonline.com/word/animus?ref=etymonline_crossreference))](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=unanimous)

But why 致? 致, and its 本義,  does not appear to mean 'mind'...please see [CUHK](https://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E8%87%B4) below.

> Synopsis  : 甲骨文表示人把東西送到面前，本義是致送、送到。

| **Parts of Speech** | **English Definitions** |
| --- | --- |
| **v.** | to send, to deliver; to convey to (arch.); cause, incur, bring about, occasion, result in; retire, resign; extend to; apply to; transmit; devote |

Comment: basically, you misused the tools, the cuhk site is for **single character only**. “一致” is a word composed by 2 characters, try the 國語辭典, which explained as “趨向合一，沒有不同。” https://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/dictView.jsp?ID=149567&q=1&word=一致   for comparison, your method is like, comprehend the word “hotdog”, but fixate on the word “dog”. i would suggest you make some adjustments, otherwise, your learning experience would be, . . . . painful 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"致" has the meaning of "deliver(傳達)" and "present(表示); "一" has the meaning of "相同". The words combined means "相同的傳達/表示" - "unanimous".

致 - https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E8%87%B4

一 - https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E4%B8%80